# Ideas for parsing netstat results for active connections

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, grep, scripting

I have several remote devices that create reverse ssh connections back to my server, so that I ssh to them and manage them remotely.  They connect back to me via a custom port.  When I do a `netstat -an | grep 127.0.0.0.1:` on my server, I get a list of devices that are currently connected.  The output looks like this:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6001          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6002          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6003          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Where 600x is the port the device is connected on.
My question is this. I want to make a script that i can run on my server that shows which devices are current connected.  I want to have config file that the script would read that lists my devices like this:

```
NORTH:6001

SOUTH:6002

EAST:6003

WEST:6004
```

and the script would parse the output of the `netstat` command and the output would look like this:

Active connections:
NORTH, SOUTH, EAST

Inactive connections:
WEST

I hope this isn't too confusing. Is this something that can be done with grep and awk?

Comment: "parse-netstat" module from App-ParseNetstat (https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/App-ParseNetstat/bin/parse-netstat) can parse the output of "netstat" command and provide output in JSON format.

Comment: I don't think you meant "127.0.0.0.1" in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three steps here

1. Just extract active port names from netstat

   `netstat -an | grep 127.0.0.1: | awk -F "[ :]+" '{print $5}'`

the `awk` specifies group of spaces and colons as separators and picks up the port id only.

2. Compare these ports from the device list file (say named `device_list.txt`), by using grep and output of the command in step 1 as pattern

   `netstat -an | grep 127.0.0.1: | awk -F "[ :]+" '{print $5}' | grep -f - device_list.txt`

This will give an output like this

```
NORTH:6001
SOUTH:6002
EAST:6003
```

3. The inactive connections can be obtained by using a `-v` in the grep

   `netstat -an | grep 127.0.0.1: | awk -F "[ :]+" '{print $5}' | grep -v -f - device_list.txt`

The output of this is

```
WEST:6004
```

You could then script around the above to print in any format you want

Comment: I thought that your code didnt work, but I see that you added an extra .0 in the netstat command.  This code works just fine.  Exactly what I needed.  Thanks!